# ASP.NET Gridview not outputting all data for a specific query

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, data-binding

They're must be a minor error somewhere in my code that im not seeing as to why on my web page , the gridview only outputs one row when i know the query works/

[Both rows from management studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsDeS.png)

[Only one row in ASP page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vub1i.jpg)

heres my c#

```
string AdminID = Request.QueryString["ID"];
string AdminsCurrentLocation = Request.QueryString["Location"]; 
 //retrieve admin location

    try
    {
        string connectionString = "Data Source=SQL5027.HostBuddy.com;Initial Catalog=DB_A05369_WATERQ;User Id=DB_A05369_WATERQ_admin;Password=waterqws1";
        //
        // Create new SqlConnection object.
        //
        using (SqlConnection connection5 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {


            connection5.Open();

            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM [DB_A05369_WATERQ].[dbo].[S_CONTROL] WHERE LOGIN = '" + AdminID + "'", connection5))
            {
                //
                // Invoke ExecuteReader method.
                //
                using (SqlDataReader reader2 = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    reader2.Read();
                    TempLocationIdbox.Text = (reader2["ALL_LOCATION_ACCESS"].ToString());
                }

            }
            connection5.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { }

    if(TempLocationIdbox.Text == "Y")
    {
        string strSQLconnection = "Data Source=SQL5027.HostBuddy.com;Initial Catalog=DB_A05369_WATERQ;User Id=DB_A05369_WATERQ_admin;Password=waterqws1";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ACT.ROW_ID , ACT.CREATED , MEM.FIRST_NAME , MEM.LAST_NAME , LOC.NAME , CAT.NAME , SER.NAME , EMP.FIRST_NAME , EMP.LAST_NAME , SER.DURATION , ACT.CASH , COS.NAME , ACT.COMMENTS FROM " +
                                                "S_ACTIVITY ACT, S_LOCATION LOC, S_CATEGORY CAT, S_EMPLOYEE EMP, S_SERVICE SER, S_COST_CODE COS, S_MEMBER MEM " +
                                                "WHERE ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID AND ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID AND ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID AND ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID AND ACT.LOCATION_ID = LOC.ROW_ID AND ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID", sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        //collect rowID
        string retrievedROWID = "";

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            string temp1 = reader["ROW_ID"].ToString();
            retrievedROWID = temp1;
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
    else if (TempLocationIdbox.Text == "N")
    {
        string strSQLconnection1 = "Data Source=SQL5027.HostBuddy.com;Initial Catalog=DB_A05369_WATERQ;User Id=DB_A05369_WATERQ_admin;Password=waterqws1";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection1);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM S_LOCATION WHERE NAME = '" + AdminsCurrentLocation + "'", sqlConnection1);
        sqlConnection1.Open();

        string locationrowID = "";
        SqlDataReader reader12 = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader12.HasRows)
        {
            reader12.Read();
            locationrowID = reader12["ROW_ID"].ToString();
        }

        sqlConnection1.Close();

        string strSQLconnection = "Data Source=SQL5027.HostBuddy.com;Initial Catalog=DB_A05369_WATERQ;User Id=DB_A05369_WATERQ_admin;Password=waterqws1";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(strSQLconnection);
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("SELECT DISTINCT ACT.ROW_ID , ACT.CREATED , MEM.FIRST_NAME , MEM.LAST_NAME , LOC.NAME , CAT.NAME , SER.NAME , EMP.FIRST_NAME , EMP.LAST_NAME , SER.DURATION , ACT.CASH , COS.NAME , ACT.COMMENTS FROM "+
                                "S_ACTIVITY ACT, S_LOCATION LOC, S_CATEGORY CAT, S_EMPLOYEE EMP, S_SERVICE SER, S_COST_CODE COS, S_MEMBER MEM "+
                                "WHERE ACT.EMPLOYEE_ID = EMP.ROW_ID AND ACT.SERVICE_ID = SER.ROW_ID AND ACT.CATEGORY_ID = CAT.ROW_ID AND ACT.COST_CODE_ID = COS.ROW_ID AND "+
                                "ACT.LOCATION_ID = '"+ locationrowID + "' AND ACT.MEMBER_ID = MEM.ROW_ID AND LOC.NAME = '"+ AdminsCurrentLocation + "'", sqlConnection);
        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        //collect rowID
        string retrievedROWID = "";

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            reader.Read();
            string temp1 = reader["ROW_ID"].ToString();
            retrievedROWID = temp1;
            GridView1.DataSource = reader;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        sqlConnection.Close();
    }
```

What stumps me is that my other query is working fine for the case where TempLocationIdbox.Text == "Y"...
Thanks , any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're only read one row from your readers. You'll probably need a while loop  to handle multiple rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `if (reader.HasRows)` you need to use `while (reader.Read())`.Also created some kind of collection for example `List<T>` and populate it with results inside the `while` loop.Then **outside the loop** set the `DataSource` of the `GridView` control to point to `List<T>`.Here's a complete example:

```
public class Activity
{
    public int RowID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

public partial class UsingSqlDataReader : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            this.GetData();
        }
    }

    private void GetData()
    {
        string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ConnectionString;
        var activities = new List<Activity>();
        using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
        {
            using(var cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ACT.ROW_ID,ACT.CREATED,ACT.FIRST_NAME FROM [dbo].[S_ACTIVITY] ACT", con))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
                con.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        var activity = new Activity();
                        activity.RowID = Convert.ToInt32(reader["ROW_ID"]);
                        activity.Created = DateTime.Parse(reader["CREATED"].ToString());
                        activity.FirstName = Convert.ToString(reader["FIRST_NAME"]);
                        activities.Add(activity);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        GridView1.DataSource = activities;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

**Output:**

[image: Populating GridView using SqlDataReader]

Comment: Got it working with a similar fashion to this , tyvm :)

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be to put your in-line query in a stored proc and execute the stored proc.

You could also bring it in a dataset and bind the gridview with that. but that is completely your choice.

In-line queries are very error prone and results could be unpredictable hence refrain using that.

Comment: *In-line queries are very error prone and results could be unpredictable ...* is it really? What if you miss that in stored proc as well? Kind of query OP is executing it has nothing to do with stored proc and better of be a inline query. How do you think this actually answer the question in hand?